# What is the story of Hiranyakashipu's son Mandara?

Tags: asuras, shiva, mahabharata, vishnu-purana

In the Anusasana Parva of the Mahabharata, in the course of recounting to Krishna the boons that Shiva has bestowed upon various people, the sage Upamanyu [describes](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a014.htm) a certain son of the demon [Hiranyakashipu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiranyakashipu) named Mandara:

> He who was the foremost of all [of Hiranyakashipu's] sons and who was celebrated by the name of Mandara, succeeded, through the boon he had obtained from Mahadeva, in fighting Sakra for a million of years. The terrible discus of Vishnu and the thunderbolt of Indra were both unable to make the slightest impression, O Kesava, in days of yore, upon the body of that great cause of universal affliction....  Even the weapon, O Kesava, failed to make the slightest impression on the body of Hiranyakashipu's son Mandara, that appeared like an evil planet in the three worlds. Hundreds of Chakras like thine and thunderbolts like that of Sakra, could not inflict a scratch on the body of that evil planet endued with great might, who had obtained a boon from Mahadeva. Afflicted by the mighty Mandara, the deities fought hard against him and his associates, all of whom had obtained boons from Mahadeva.

My question is, is there any information known about the story of Mandara?  The Vishnu Purana [says](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp050.htm) "Hirańyakaśipu was the father of four mighty sons, Anuhláda, Hláda, the wise Prahláda, and the heroic Sanhláda, the augmentor of the Daitya race."  (The Daityas are a race of demons descended from the sage Kashyap and his wife Diti.) Is Mandara an alternate name for one of these sons?  If so I assume that it would be Sanhlada, because he's said to be "the augmentor of the Daitya race", so he presumably increased their territory or something.

In any case, where does Mandara's battle with the gods fit in chronologically?  It was my understanding that Hiranyakashipu was succeeded as king of the Asuras (demons) by Prahlada, Prahlada was succeeded by Virochana, and Virochana was succeeded by Mahabali.  So in relation to these kings of the Asuras, when did Mandara fight the gods?  And more importantly, how did the gods ultimately get around Shiva's boon and defeat Mandara?

EDIT:  I found a passage in the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata which [says](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01066.htm) that Hiranyakashipu actually had five sons:

> And the illustrious Hiranyakasipu had five sons, all famous throughout the world. The eldest of them all was Prahlada, the next was Sahradha; the third was Anuhrada; and after him were Sivi and Vashkala.

So is it possible that Sivi or Vashkala is an alternate name for Mandara?

Comment: Curious to know this too, my google-fu even failed.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yeaj, the problem is that searching for Hiranyakashipu and Mandara keeps turning up the fact that Hiranyakshipu meditated on Mount Mandara.  And searching for the phrase "Hiranyakashipu's son Mandara" only turns up references to this passage in the Mahabharata.

Comment: Same happening to me.

Comment: Actually, that Hiranyakashipu you mentioned is not the Daitya, he is a Danava. So, i think there are two Hiranyakashipus.