# Who is the descendant of Bhrigu who heard the famous Vakratunda mantra to Ganesha from the gods?

Tags: puranas, mantras, ganesha, narada-purana

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8059/36), the sage who heard many Ganesha mantras from gods was Ganaka, who I speculated may have been an incarnation of Ganesha himself.  Now I have found a mantra to Ganesha that seems to have been heard from the gods by another sage: the famous Vakratunda mantra.  Here is what [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/FLBf) from the Narada Purana says about it:

> **Bhargava is its sage**, the metre is anushtup, the lord is Ganadhipa.  (he who) is called Vakratunda is the Bija (the seed), Vam is Shakti and Kavacha (coat of mail).

My question is, who is the "Bhargava" sage who heard the Vakratunda mantra from the gods?

For those who don't know, Bhargava just means descendant of the sage Bhrigu, which encompasses one seventh of all the Brahmins in the world.  It applies to Sukracharya guru of the Asuras (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3527/36) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3434/36)), the sage Dadhichi (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2527/36) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7729/36)), Vishnu's incarnation Parashurama, and me!  (I'm a Vathula Gotra Brahmana.)

So which descendant of Bhrigu are we talking about here?  Are there any other scriptures which describe the Vakratunda mantra and the sage who heard it from the gods?