# Is it possible to attain moksha with Dhyana yoga?

Tags: yoga, yoga-sutras, raja-yoga, hatha-yoga

Is it possible in this century and this lifetime to attain salvation through Dhyana Yoga? (One of the 4 yogas to attain salvation as per Gita)
Could you give names of some dhyana yogis who achieved salvation in this or the previous century?
By Dhyana Yoga I mean meditation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Raja-yoga? Is it related to Jnana-Yoga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-raja-yoga-is-it-related-to-jnana-yoga)

Comment: By "dhyana-yoga" do you mean Raja Yoga only?

Comment: @Vivikta Bhagavad Gita chapter 6 is called dhyana yoga. Probably that's what OP is referring to.

Comment: @zero maybe yes. They should clearly state that, because they tagged the "raja-yoga".

Comment: Question is not clear...:

Comment: What is the definition of Dhyana yoga you are asking?

Answer (score 3):

```
Is it possible in this century to attain salvation through Dhyana Yoga?
```

**Yes**. It is possible to attain salvation through Dhyana yoga. A chapter in Mahabharatha explicitly mentions it. However, the chapter contains more detailed information about Dhyana yoga. I am presenting only relevant parts that stress the moksha-giving capability of Dhyana yoga.

> "Bhishma said, 'I shall now, O son of Pritha, discourse to thee upon
> the four kinds of **yoga meditation**. The great Rishis, obtaining a
> knowledge of the same, **attain to eternal success even here**. Great
> Rishis gratified with knowledge, with hearts set upon Emancipation,
> and conversant with yoga, act in such a way that their yoga meditation
> may get on properly. **These, O son of Pritha, being freed from the
> faults of the world, never come back (for rebirth). Liberated from
> liability to rebirth, they live in their original
> Soul-state**............ The man that acts in this way succeeds in
> controlling them. One, O Bharata, by oneself directing one's mind and
> senses to the path of meditation, succeeds in bringing them under
> perfect control by steadfast yoga. The felicity that he feels who has
> succeeded in controlling his mind and senses is such that its like can
> never be obtained through Exertion or Destiny. United with such
> felicity, he continues to take a pleasure in the act of meditation.
> **Even in this way yogins attain to Nirvana which is highly blessed**.'"
>
> [[Section 195, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/index.htm)

The meditation in this chapter stands for Dhyana; hence, Yoga meditation refers to Dhyana yoga. You can understand it from the [Sanskrit version of the chapter](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs12188.htm).

I don't know why you presumed the time boundness for results of Dhyana yoga. There are no restrictions on time for attaining liberation through Dhyana yoga. One can attain moksha in any century with the help of Dhyana yoga.

Comment: I think Vivekananda is a popular example of a Dhyana yogi.

Comment: Ramana maharshi is another example.

Comment: Thx this is very helpful 