# Merge of Karma & Bhakti into Jnana

Tags: karma, practice, bhakti, jnana

Read my previous [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8475/277) where I said that I think/believe that other ways should merge into Jnana ultimately but this can be considered as my opinion only. The scriptural reference supporting this is essential.

Also remember that Jnana here is not limited to scriptural knowledge only but consider it as Vijanana (Realization of absolute/ultimate truth) also (as mentioned in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8788/277) answer :  Jnana is simply referring to Vijnana).

So, I am looking for any scriptural reference which say Karma & Bhakti ultimately merges into Jnana.

If you know any scriptural reference/support about this topic, then you are requested to answer with quotation of authentic scripture.

Comment: Sri Vaishnavas believe that Bhakti Yoga is the route to Jnana, but that Bhakti Yoga also involves doing Karma Yoga and Jnana Yoga.  In fact Bhakti Yoga involves meditating on the 32 Brahmavidyas that I told you about before.  Sri Vaishnavas also believe that you can skip doing any of these three Yogas and instead just do Sharanagati, complete surrender to Vishnu.

Comment: Good question. Think of a big painting of Eiffel Tower. One onlooker excalims 'what a beautiful painting! the colors are so vivid!', another onlooker exclaims 'what a beautiful painting! the clouds, the majesty, the Light'. Although both of them are looking at the same painting, different aspects of it appeal to them. Similarly, Brahman is the source of Eternal Happiness! The Jnanis try to seek 'Happiness' by seeking Truth. The Bhaktas try to seek 'Happiness' by seeking Love. The Karma's try to seek 'Happiness' by seeking Peace. Love, Truth and Peace are all different aspects of the Self :).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29580655#29580655

Answer (score 5):

#### Merge of Bhakti into Jnana:

According to Bhagavad Gita, verse 10.10 & 10.11 (English translation from [Gitapress](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0zBCVuV7cUDRJNTJIX01obG8/view)):

> तेषां सततयुक्तानां भजतां प्रीतिपूर्वकम् ।
>   ददामि बुद्धियोगं तं येन मामुपयान्ति ते ॥
>
> On those ever united through meditation with Me and worshipping Me with love, I confer that **Yoga of wisdom** by which they come to Me.
>
> तेषामेवानुकम्पार्थमहमज्ञानजं तमः ।
>   नाशयाम्यात्मभावस्थो ज्ञानदीपेन भास्वता ॥
>
> In order to bestow My compassion on them, I, dwelling in their hearts, dispel their darkness born of ignorance by the illuminating **lamp of knowledge**.

In above verses, Krishna says that he gives devotees right understanding and jnana which means person following Bhakti path will get Jnana hence they will attain absolute/ultimate truth.

According to Bhagvatam, [verse 1.2.7](http://srimadbhagavatam.org/canto1/chapter2.html#Text%207):

> वासुदेवे भगवति भक्तियोगः प्रयोजितः
>    जनयत्याशु वैराग्यं ज्ञानं च यदहैतुकम्
>
> The practice of connecting oneself in devotion unto Vâsudeva, the Personality of Godhead, very soon **leads to the detachment and spiritual knowledge** that relies on its own power.

#### Merge of Karma into Jnana:

According to Bhagavad-Gita, verse 4.37 & 4.38:

> यथैधांसि समिद्धोऽग्निर्भस्मसात्कुरुतेऽर्जुन ।
>   ज्ञानाग्निः सर्वकर्माणि भस्मसात्कुरुते तथा ॥
>
> As a blazing ﬁre turns ﬁrewood to ashes, O Arjuna,
>  so does the ﬁre of knowledge burn to ashes all reactions to material activities.
>
> न हि ज्ञानेन सदृशं पवित्रमिह विद्यते ।
>   तत्स्वयं योगसंसिद्धः कालेनात्मनि विन्दति ॥
>
> In this world, there is nothing so sublime and pure as transcendental knowledge. Such **knowledge is the mature fruit of all mysticism**. And one who has become accomplished in the practice of devotional service enjoys this knowledge within himself in due course of time.

---

I've referenced the (Smriti) Bhagavad Gita for the point of the question. Though I will add the reference from (Shruti) Upanishads....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very appropriate as it includes proper submissive inquiry. That is implied from [Bhagavad Gita 4.34](http://www.vedabase.com/bg/4/34)

The topmost path is Bhakti Yoga (although 99% population conclude jnana wrongly). This fact is based on multiple verses from Vedas. The Bhagavad Gita, which is condensed summary of all Vedas for this age is sufficient to prove this fact in multiple verse, such as:

yoginām api sarveṣāṁ
mad-gatenāntar-ātmanā
śraddhāvān bhajate yo māṁ
sa me yukta-tamo mataḥ

And of all yogīs, the one with great faith who always abides in Me, thinks of Me within himself and renders transcendental loving service to Me – he is the most intimately united with Me in yoga and is the highest of all. That is My opinion. ([BG 6.47](http://www.vedabase.com/bg/6/47))

When on multiple instructions Arjuna was confused regarding which is topmost (inaction in knowledge (jnana) or action in devotion (bhakti through Karma-yoga)) in verse [5.1](http://www.vedabase.com/bg/5/1)

Krishna replies that both are non-different and shall lead to same path (bhakti yoga as concluded in 6.47) but for people of Kali-yuga or iron age, most practical is Acting in devotion ([BG 5.2](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/5/2))

Therefore all paths ultimately conclude in Bhakti Yoga. The Yoga Ladder goes like this:

Karma-kanda -> Karma yoga -> Jnana Yoga -> Ashtanga Yoga -> Bhakti Yoga

You must read Chapter 6 of Bhagavad Gita to conclude the impracticality of Jnana yoga in this age.