# What is the need of creation?

Tags: puranas, upanishads, creation

Questions [How was the Universe created?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/how-was-the-universe-created/8525#8525) and [What is the source of creation according to Upanishads?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/what-is-the-source-of-creation-according-to-upanishads) talk about many aspects of creation. But my questions are:

- What is the need of creation? Why Brahma wants to become many?
- What will happen if nothing will exist in this universe? Will it affect Iswara?
- Is there any relation between existence of Supreme Brahma, Devas and human?

Comment: From Advaitic perspective, neither there was creation nor destruction. It was just Maya. [Yoga Vasista](http://estudantedavedanta.net/The-Supreme-Yoga-Swami-Venkatesananda.pdf) explains this with many examples.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, but some other sects like dvait and some puranas, upanishads accepts the creation.

Comment: To some extent they are expl. by  Law of Karma... cause-effect-cause and Brahman as witness... When finally logic of concept of Karma and cause and effect fails then concept of [Lila](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lila_(Hinduism)) comes. Regarding Advaita perspectives you may be interested in my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/according-to-shankaracharya-in-advaita-is-the-universe-unreal-or-unworthy/13596#13596) and [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11295/what-is-the-position-of-mayaillusion-as-per-advaita-doctrine-or-according-to/12347#12347)

Comment: @Tezz Thanks. I am also thinking in the same way. But there must be some concrete reason described in some puranas. I cannot totally recall but I have read somewhere similar topic in some puranas in hindi.

Comment: What is the need of creation? Nobody knows the answer. It is natural. It is called 'His play' by some and 'His will' by some. However this is a question that cannot be answered. Because logically you can keep asking why. However the sages say that instead of asking why you can change the question to 'Who'. Who are you, that asks this question? Who are you, are you the body, that is created? or the mind, that is changing, or the changeless eternal supreme Self!? The answer to this question will liberate you from bondage and give you complete Shanthi!

Comment: @Sai Sir I will not repeatedly ask why if I will get some logical answer. Infact I welcome your view. It seems to be very rational. But I think atleast my second question can be answered here. I will welcome those answers too that will discuss a single part of question.

Comment: I think you can get answer only by attaining the absolute truth! (Because we i.e our mind and intellect can't realize the ultimate reality; for e.g. what do you mean by *creation*? may be the illusory!)

Comment: @Pandya I don't think I am going to attain absolute truth in near future. Yes in Advait creation may be illusory but some other sects consider creation, preservation and destruction as natural process.

Comment: @Triyugi If nothing existed, then it will not affect Ishwara. Because by definition Ishwara is Self effulgent and Embodiment of Bliss. He does not depend on us for His Happiness although we depend on Him. That's why all logical reasoning stops when you ask 'why'. It has to end in 'His will' or 'His play'. Simple as that. 'Is there any relation between ...' you need to clarify because its not clear what you're looking for in the last part of the subquestion.

Comment: @Sai Thanks for clarification. For the last point I have read a theory that Devas got strength from the yajna performed by human being. In that way, if there will not be any human being then Devas become week. Now I just want to know will it also affect Ishara?

Comment: This a very sloppy question, conflating many different things. Brahmā and Parambrahman are different living entities and have different reasons for creation. Creation itself is of two different kinds, kalpa and vikalpa. First you should ask about that. Please ask one question per question. There is no limit on stackexchange, the more questions, the better. The more refined and precise they are, the better. Please do not presuppose things, if uncertain. This question can be refined into several good questions.

Comment: @user3603546 Thanks for your suggestion but let's suppose I do not know Kalpa and Vikalpa, then how can I ask about that? And to clarify Brahma, I have linked questions related to it. So you may go to that question and read. And last I have asked three questions those all are inter-related. For the clarification of this point you may again look into linked questions. So, I don't think its sloppy.

Comment: Linked duplicate [Why Brahma created universe?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19454/1049).

Comment: @iammilind you can also post your answer here as partial answer.

Comment: Triyugi ji Brahman didn't become many. The many ness always existed. https://himalayanhermit.com/six-anadi-six-beginningless-substances/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Sankara there is no creation. There is only *vivarta vada* - apparent manifestation.

Swami Vivekananda says (*[Complete Works](http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_3/vol_3_frame.htm)*, V3, pp 12-14, also available here under the heading *[Lectures and Discourses](http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_3/lectures_and_discourses/lectures_and_discourses_contents.htm)*, sub-heading *[The Free Soul](http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_3/lectures_and_discourses/the_free_soul.htm)*):

> Before going into the practical part, we will take up one more intellectual question. So far the logic is tremendously rigorous. If man reasons, there is no place for him to stand until he comes to this, that there is but One Existence, that everything else is nothing. There is no other way left for rational mankind but to take this view. But how is it that what is infinite, ever perfect, ever blessed, Existence-Knowledge-Bliss Absolute, has come under these delusions? It is the same question that has been asked all the world over. In the vulgar form the question becomes, "How did sin come into this world?" This is the most vulgar and sensuous form of the question, and the other is the most philosophic form, but the answer is the same. The same question has been asked in various grades and fashions, but in its lower forms it finds no solution, because the stories of apples and serpents and women do not give the explanation. In that state, the question is childish, and so is the answer. But the question has assumed very high proportions now: "How did this illusion come?" And the answer is as fine. The answer is that we cannot expect any answer to an impossible question. The very question is impossible in terms. You have no right to ask that question. Why? What is perfection? That which is beyond time, space, and causation — that is perfect. Then you ask how the perfect became imperfect. In logical language the question may be put in this form: "How did that which is beyond causation become caused?" You contradict yourself. You first admit it is beyond causation, and then ask what causes it. This question can only be asked within the limits of causation. As far as time and space and causation extend, so far can this question be asked. But beyond that it will be nonsense to ask it, because the question is illogical. Within time, space, and causation it can never be answered, and what answer may lie beyond these limits can only be known when we have transcended them; therefore the wise will let this question rest. When a man is ill, he devotes himself to curing his disease without insisting that he must first learn how he came to have it.
>
> There is another form of this question, a little lower, but more practical and illustrative: What produced this delusion? Can any reality produce delusion? Certainly not. We see that one delusion produces another, and so on. It is delusion always that produces delusion. It is disease that produces disease, and not health that produces disease. The wave is the same thing as the water, the effect is the cause in another form. The effect is delusion, and therefore the cause must be delusion. What produced this delusion? Another delusion. And so on without beginning. The only question that remains for you to ask is: Does not this break your monism, because you get two existences in the universe, one yourself and the other the delusion? The answer is: Delusion cannot be called an existence. Thousands of dreams come into your life, but do not form any part of your life. Dreams come and go; they have no existence. To call delusion existence will be sophistry. Therefore there is only one individual existence in the universe, ever free, and ever blessed; and that is what you are. This is the last conclusion reached by the Advaitists.

So to answer your question more directly, there is no 'need' for creation. Why did Brahma want to become many? Do you mean Brahman or Brahma? If Brahman, the Upanishads simply say that he became many. The Taittiriya Upanishad (3.1) says:

> That from which these beings are born, by which they live after birth and into which they they enter at death--try to know That. That is Brahman.

And the Aitareya Upanishad (1.1.1-2) says:

> This universe, my dear, was but the Real (Sat) in the beginning--One only without a second [ekamevadvitiyam]. It thought, 'may I be many, (the Atman) willed, "Let me project world!' So It projected these worlds.

Your next question is not logical. You ask - what will happen if nothing will exist in this universe? If the universe exists, then *something* exists - the universe implies existence, if not of anything else, of the 5 subtle elements.

Iswara is simply the Nirguna Brahman seen through the lens of maya. Our brains are too small and must think in terms of name and form. We cannot conceive of That which is beyond name and form, so we give the Unmanifest a name and form so that we can try to comprehend It.

What is the relation between the Brahman, the Devas, and human? It is all One simply appearing as many. The devas and humans are all jivas that are caught in the meshes of maya. It is all Brahman. The Chandogya Upanishad says (3.14.1):

> All this is verily Brahman.

Comment: How can something be eternal (like delusion) and doesn't exist? Only truth must be eternal and that is Brahman or Atman. If we attain status of **Jeevanmukta**, delusion ends for us and so delusion is not eternal. I think no one can explain "**Why delusion exists**"? because we live in this delusion. I think even **Jeevanmukta** can't explain it because now delusion stops him from explaining. We can only know after realizing.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This answer is from Bhagavad Gita perspective.</sub>

```
What is the need of creation? Why Brahma wants to become many?
```

**Neither need nor any reason to create the universe**.
Also *Brahman* (or *Brahma*) should be interpreted as **in one-ness**, whether it is one or many.

> BG 9.8 - Keeping "My" nature (*prakruti*) under control, "I" create [& destroy] the world of beings again & again; which are helpless under the nature (*prakruti*)
>   BG 9.9 - And O Arjuna, those actions (*Karma*-s) don't bind Me, as I am **uninterested & detached** to them
>   BG 9.10 - Under "My" supervision, the *Prakruti* produces moving & non-moving [beings]; With[out] this purpose the world **repeats**

---

```
What will happen if nothing will exist in this universe? Will it affect Iswara?
```

Indeed the ***nothingness*** (or *[ShunyatA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9A%C5%ABnyat%C4%81)*) is the ultimate reality, which many refer as supreme God or ***Iswara***. Hence, we can deduce that there is nothing really existed, exists & will exist.

> BG 8.20 - But different from that "unmanifested", is the another **eternal "unmanifest" reality**, which is not destroyed when all beings are destroyed.
>   BG 13.13 - I shall speak of that which is knowable. Knowing which, one attains immortality. The supreme Brahman devoted to 'Me', is beginning-less. 'That' is said to be **neither existent nor non-existent**. (existent = being)

Like, when we are dreaming, so much time passes and things also look real. Only upon waking up, we find that, less time has passed & it was an imagination. Similarly, whatever is manifesting currently for us, looks "real" to us, can be interpreted as being imagined.
<sub>This is also the core theme of movie [Inception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception)</sub>.

> BG 9.7 — O son of Kunti, all elementary world becomes "My" nature at end of cycle(Kalpa); Again "I" create them at the beginning of the cycle.

---

```
Is there any relation between existence of Supreme Brahma[n], Devas and humans?
```

The supreme Brahman or "Me" or whatever is the ultimate reality -- is not perceivable as discussed above. Which is depicted as *"Nirguna"* (beyond formless). The other aspect is *"Saguna"* (formful or formless). That is the cause of everything existent. It keeps happening as part of [Eternal Return](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return#Indian_religions):

- "Everything" comes into being out of "Nothing"
- All beings keep mutating; This existence remains for "X" duration
- "Everything" vanishes into "Nothing"; This non-existence remains for "X" duration

> BG 8.18 - On arrival of day, all manifestations originate from "Unmanifest"; On arrival of night they annihilate into [what is] known as "Unmanifest" only.
>   BG 8.19 - **This [same] elementary world only happens again & again**; Annihilates upon arrival of night, [and] originates upon arrival of day.

Mainly *Brahman*, *Deva*-s & humans **have a relation of time**, i.e. "X" duration.

If a consciousness (*Purusha*) is at the level of:

- **"Me" / *Atma***, then X + X = 0 (no time)
- ***Brahman***, then X + X = 1 Day + 1 Night of *Brahman*
- ***Deva***, then X + X = several days of *Deva*
- ***Pitru***, then X + X = several years of *Pitru*
- **Humans**, then X + X = several eras of Humans

There can be intermediate planes as well. Refer the section [Q-2 in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16085/1049) for the scripture proof.
BTW, after humans, there are further lower planes of existence: like animals, insects, bacteria, ... Lower the plane, more the time is spent to realise the supreme reality. Once reached at lowest, again there is a sense of "no time" (i.e. "Me").

If a person has more *Sattva* mode (goodness), it journeys towards "Me" by going to higher regions than humans; with more *Tamas* mode (ignorance), one journeys towards "Me" by going to lower regions than humans. The mode of *Rajas* (passion/desire) only binds to any particular plane.

> BG 14.18 - Those with *sattva* go higher [regions]; those with *rajas* stay in the middle; those with *tamas*, having despicable actions, go [further] down.

Comment: Shunyata is Buddhist concept. I think you misinterpreted na Sat and na Asat ."na sat, na asat" is explained in Neti Neti approach (not this, not this) as it is beyond words. It doesn't mean Brahman is Shunyata. You can check Adi Shankara commentary here. http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-13-13/

Comment: @TheDestroyer, It doesn't matter if *ShunyatA* is a buddhist concept or not. That is like saying, "newton's laws" are English concept or "relativity" is German concept. When you apply "Neti Neti", ultimately "Nothing" remains. In math we call it "0" or "void" to be precise. These terms are derived from "ShunyatA". In fact "ShunyatA" objectified the supreme reality, which was unknown till then. During Krishna's time, the concept of "void" was not there. Hence Krishna referred it as "I". That is also logical, because after applying "Neti Neti" on everything, only "I" remains who did "neti neti".

Comment: @iammilind So by saying that God is "nothing", are you saying that God does not exist? What are your personal beliefs BTW?

Comment: @Vick, if X says god "existent" and Y says that the god "non existent"; then either both are true or both are false. Bcoz as said in BG 13.13 above: *"That' is said to be neither existent nor non-existent."* (That = God). Now, What is God? If we term it as some superior being who functions all, then that "something" should have been created. Because "something" or "everything" or "anything" are always with respect to "nothing". Whatever is created will be destroyed as it was not existing before creation. This's why many apply "Neti Neti" to realise God. Ultimately the remain will be "Nothing".