# Why did Brahma create Universe?

Tags: brahma, creation

We all know that Brahma is the creator of Universe and this is why Universe is also called as Bramhand(universe). But why has he created Bramhand? What was the purpose behind?

Comment: Why we use to give birth to children? Same way Brahma created us. This one line has very deep meaning to understand.

Comment: @Rishabh But why he wanted us to be there ? What is the purpose behind it ?

Comment: You can get this answer by your father, Just ask him "why did you give me birth?". Every parent want someone to care for and also want to be cared by someone. Brahma also wanted to have someone as family. Tridevas treats us as their children. And parents gives birth to children without any greed But just to get love from them and also to give love. Soul purpose is Love.

Comment: I am sorry your logic is valid but I am not really convinced with that. Because "to have something to take care he created us?" As he already had their sons and a daughter to look after.

Comment: "As he already had their sons and a daughter to look after"... Saints never differentiate between their children and others. For them every human are equal. Besides when Lord krishna showed his universal form (Virat swaroop) to Arjuna then he got scared by seeing that form of him and asked who are you in actual. Then Krishna replied..."Partha, your mind is not capable to understand reason or source of my existance. I am the supreme creator of universe. Carores of galaxies is created by my wish. Whenever I wish..[continue]

Comment: I created and whenever I wish I destroyed galaxies. Like that carores of Galaxies is being created from me and got destroyed and comes inside me again. It's all game/play of my wish.

Comment: And also Brahma created his children just to help humans to grow. For example.. He created Saptarishi so that they can spread knowledge in world. He created Yamraj to give punishment for human's bad deeds and he created Daksha to teach humans art of living and devotion and so on... All his children were only for humans. He didn't create them for himself but instead for us.

Comment: " They why us? Why we exist for who he created his children? " what is the sole purpose of creating universe. Taking care of us does not seem convincing yet.

Comment: You are seeing from mind. Just try to understand with devotion/Love then your whole doubt will be cleared. You will understand everything on your own.

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/what-is-the-need-of-creation

Answer (score 1):

Lord created Universe and all living and non living things. But why he created us? What was his need that he want to fulfill from us? Most important question is what he want from us? There must be something that Lord want from us that's why he created us.

Now think, What human possibly can give to Lord. Actually first think what you have that you can offer to Lord. Let's see what you have that you can give to Lord...

- You have life, so you can offer your life to Lord. BUT wait... that life is not your because this life of your is given by Lord to you. So it's Lord's gift to you. So there is no way you can gift life to Lord because it's already Lord's.
- What more you have... Hmm May be money. You can offer Gold, diamonds and other luxuries items to Lord. But wait, It's Lord who created Diamonds, Golds and all other things and gives it to humans. So whatever you have is because of Lord. So It's already of Lord's, not your. Lord use to give those worldly items to their Devotees. You can return those things (luxuries) back to Lord But that won't be any Gift to Lord because you are giving Lord's thing back to Lord. You are not giving your own thing.

So humans are useless to offer anything to Lord. Because whatever humans have is because of Lord. He gave all to humans. Humans himself has nothing.

Now the main question is... What humans can give to Lord?

Answer is very simple. One thing that we can offer to Lord is Love. Only this thing is we have which is our and we can give that to Lord. And this is the only thing that Lord want from us (Nothing else). He don't want your money, land Property or your life. Because these all were given to you by Lord. If he wants those items then why Lord give all those to you. Couldn't he just keep all to himself if Lord really wants those things? He don't want your money but he wants your Love.

Humans can't offer to Lord anything except Love. love is the need of Lord because Lord is Love himself. He Loves us that's why he created us and that's the reason he has given so many things to us And in return He only wants us to be nice. He wants us to become pure soul and walk on path of Dharma. Lord wants that, in which sinless or pure form Lord send you on earth, you return to Lord in the same pure Form.

Answer (score 1):

**No purpose**.
"Purpose" is an expected reaction for any action (viz. *Karma fala*). When one acts without interest & concern, there is no purpose.

> BG 9.8 - Keeping My nature (*prakruti*) under control, I create [& destroy] the world of beings again & again; which are helpless under the nature (*prakruti*)
>   BG 9.9 - And O Arjuna, those actions (*Karma*-s) don't bind Me, as I am **uninterested & detached** to them

Also read [Eternal Return](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return#Indian_religions).