# How to know What is the purpose of my life?

Tags: life

People say we need to find by ourselves the purpose we came on Earth but what if I never come to know why exactly I have been created by him and what he wants me to do?

Can someone please help me in seeking? I am not patient or knowledgeable enough to go and find by myself!!

Comment: Sometimes we ourselves can't find it. Because we all are that not much evolved spiritually. So, almost all of us will need help from our Guru. But generally speaking the goal is to merge back from where we all came. But even for that a Satguru's guidance is inevitable.

Comment: As the question is about knowing one's own specific purpose, I propose this may be helpful: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20448/how-can-one-know-their-dharma

Answer (score 3):

In the philosophical sense, if one is moving towards self realisation, then there is **absolutely no purpose** may remain in the life.

> BG 3.17 - But that person who rejoices only in self and is satisfied with the Self, and is contented only in the Self - for them **there is no duty to perform**
>   BG 3.18 - **For them there is no purpose** here at all with performing action; nor any [purpose] with nonperformance. Moreover, for them there is **no dependence on any object to serve any purpose**

Not only at macro or micro level but at broader level, the supreme [Brahman] also acts [without any purpose](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19458/1049). A person becomes **indifferent** to the results of the action (*Karma phala*) when acts without purpose. We may call it *leela* as well.

So in this sense, if you still want to have a purpose, then try to reach at the level of "Indifference". **Indifference is opposite of all the things.**

> *"The opposite of love is not hate, it's indifference. The opposite of beauty is not ugliness, it's indifference. The opposite of faith is not heresy, it's indifference. And the opposite of life is not death, but indifference between life and death." -- Elie Wiesel*

Comment: You initiated the close vote and answered the question too. I am confused on this action from you.

Comment: @SS, First I answered the Qn. After some time, I thought that this Qn should have been asked as it seems too generic. Hence searched for it. Found a similar Qn and put a close vote for the duplicate after 10 mins. BTW, the linked duplicate is quite similar, but that itself is closed for another related duplicate (little less similar).