# What's the purpose of creation of the universe?

Tags: gods, creation, universe

According to Hinduism -

1.What's the purpose of creation of the universe?

2. Why god created humans? What's the purpose?
3. Why did he create humans to be highly intelligent and animals not so much?
4. Why does he want only humans to worship him and not animals? Has he actually asked humans to worship him or are humans worshipping him by their own will?

Comment: Related: [What is the need of creation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/what-is-the-need-of-creation).