# Some questions about Brahman

Tags: vedas, brahman

I recently became very interested in Hindu mythology and would love to hear from well-read individuals who really have a thorough understanding of the Vedas. I have just 2 questions for now:

1) Why did Brahman split itself? If it is God, then why create the world? Brahman is happy and blissed out, so why?

2) Why did Brahman create pain, suffering, pure evil in this world?

Comment: First question is very philosophical. Entire millennia of interpretations have been given for it by rishis. But simple answer is 'why not?'. Second question is answered with a simple question - Do you ever bother to ask WHY did Brahman create PLEASURE, enjoyment, PURE GOOD in this world ?

Comment: Related [What is the need of creation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/what-is-the-need-of-creation)

Comment: @ram I will answer your questions to play the "devil's advocate."

1) "Why should the universe NOT create itself?" - Because of pain, evil and suffering. In the same way that Buddha renounced asceticism and self-harm, so avoiding self-harm is justification for NOT creating the universe.

2)  "Do you ever bother to ask why did Brahman create pleasure, enjoyment, pure good in this world?" 

I will answer this with another question - What good is pleasure if it is cancelled out by pain? For example, if I love and care for my dog, but then I slit his throat and eat him, what is the point?

Comment: @ss3592, pain, evil & suffering is simply the other side of the coin which is pleasure, good & enjoyment. if you want only the heads and not the tails of a coin, good luck getting one. I will also answer with another question - if you torture your dog, but don't care for it, what is the point. Note, that it's actually me playing the devil's advocate. I'm saying I want EVIL. You're saying you want GOOD. God is saying - asking for GOOD without EVIL or EVIL without GOOD is like asking for a coin with HEADS without TAILS or TAILS without HEADS. God is simply middle-man. Good & Evil are done by us.

Comment: @ss3592, but then, God seems to has a soft-corner for GOOD. why - well i don't know, it's his wish.

Comment: Thank you @ram I appreciate your input. I understand that black and white are one, good and evil are not two things but one thing. 

I liked your counter-question btw about what's the point if you just torture a dog without taking care of it lol. 

As for my original questions in the main post, I wanted to know the answers from a "mythological" point of view (i.e. the narrative point of view as discussed in the Upanishads). But I've got my answers. Thank you for engaging me :)