# What is origin, purpose and future of whole system of everything so called known and so called unknown?

Tags: life

What is the purpose, origin and future of existence of whole of everything or the whole system that include everything e.g. me, you, animals, trees, planets, viruses, bacteria,stars, galaxies and all infinite unknown macro world, atoms, electrons or infinite unknown micro/nano world?

Comment: That's the purpose of human birth

Comment: What is the purpose of human birth?

Comment: Thq question seems unclear. Can you clarify bit?

Comment: @Pandya: Why do you exist? what is your future? What is your origin? Now apply this question to all entities e.g. trees, animals, viruses, bacteria, electron, proton, atoms, planets, stars, galaxies and other infinite known and unknown. This is the question I posted which is applicable to everything.

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor I think you're looking for [What is the need of creation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13969/277)