# What are all the incidents mentioned in the scriptures where Asuras have tried to destroy the Earth?

Tags: asuras, evil

What are all the incidents mentioned in the scriptures where Asuras have tried to destroy the Earth?

I know of three: Bali's sister's [attempt to annihilate the Earth](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3321/what-is-the-story-of-mahabalis-sisters-attempt-to-destroy-the-world), Hiranyaksha's submersion of Earth into the cosmic ocean to drown all life, and Hiranyakashipu's invasion of Earth and subsequent genocide of the 4 castes and destruction of the Vedic civilization.

For example, here is what Hiranyakashipu did in his invasion of Earth, from chapter 2, canto 7 of the *Bhagavata Purana*:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What other incidents are there where Asuras have tried to completely destroy the Earth OR the Vedic civilization?

Comment: Means, destroying earth physically? @Ikshvaku

Comment: @hanugm Destroy the Earth physically OR destroy the Vedic civilization completely

Comment: Then it will be too broad right? It is better to narrowed down to a scripture say Mahabharata.

Comment: @hanugm If people flag it as too broad, I'll reduce the scope to the Mahabharata.